# periodic disconnect from wifi (reason 3)

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

I am running Lubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, which I just upgraded, and I've noticed that my machine disconnects from my home wifi about every 5-15 minutes. I'm able to reconnect immediately without issue, but it's super annoying to have to keep an eye on.

This should not be a signal quality issue, as I am right next to the router. I have not been able to find a conflicting SSID. I also followed some advice elsewhere to change `wifi.powersave = 2`, which doesn't seem to affect the issue.

This seems to be a common problem, so some advice from previous threads, I've pasted the relevant chunk of logs from `journalctl --follow` here:

```
Jan 04 14:12:04 chalchiuhtlicue kernel: wlp9s0: deauthenticated from 74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20 (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jan 04 14:12:04 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: wlp9s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20 reason=3
Jan 04 14:12:04 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <warn>  [1609791124.8639] sup-iface[0x5568015b4910,wlp9s0]: connection disconnected (reason 3)
Jan 04 14:12:04 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: wlp9s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jan 04 14:12:04 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791124.8956] device (wlp9s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jan 04 14:12:04 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791124.9692] device (wlp9s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: wlp9s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20 (SSID='ATTEqhWrMS' freq=2462 MHz)
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue kernel: wlp9s0: authenticate with 74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue kernel: wlp9s0: send auth to 74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20 (try 1/3)
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.5481] device (wlp9s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: wlp9s0: Trying to associate with 74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20 (SSID='ATTEqhWrMS' freq=2462 MHz)
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue kernel: wlp9s0: authenticated
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue kernel: wlp9s0: associate with 74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20 (try 1/3)
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.5505] device (wlp9s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue kernel: wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from 74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=3)
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: wlp9s0: Associated with 74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: wlp9s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue kernel: wlp9s0: associated
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: l2_packet_send - sendto: No buffer space available
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue kernel: wlp9s0: deauthenticating from 74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: wlp9s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=74:ea:e8:5f:e4:20 reason=1 locally_generated=1
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: wlp9s0: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: wlp9s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="ATTEqhWrMS" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=WRONG_KEY
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue wpa_supplicant[798]: wlp9s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.5675] device (wlp9s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <warn>  [1609791125.5676] sup-iface[0x5568015b4910,wlp9s0]: connection disconnected (reason -1)
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.5727] device (wlp9s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.5744] device (wlp9s0): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.5745] device (wlp9s0): state change: activated -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.6177] dhcp4 (wlp9s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.6177] dhcp4 (wlp9s0): state changed bound -> done
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.6181] dhcp6 (wlp9s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.6182] dhcp6 (wlp9s0): state changed bound -> done
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.6188] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue whoopsie[960]: [14:12:05] offline
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue dbus-daemon[755]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=756 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <warn>  [1609791125.6244] device (wlp9s0): no secrets: No agents were available for this request.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.6244] device (wlp9s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.6254] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <warn>  [1609791125.6268] device (wlp9s0): Activation: failed for connection 'ATTEqhWrMS'
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791125.6272] device (wlp9s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Withdrawing address record for 2600:1700:af40:9100::44 on wlp9s0.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Withdrawing address record for 2600:1700:af40:9100:56f5:8902:d476:2134 on wlp9s0.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp9s0.IPv6 with address 2600:1700:af40:9100:56f5:8902:d476:2134.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp9s0.IPv6 with address fe80::bd93:7147:e5f0:ea7c.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Registering new address record for fe80::bd93:7147:e5f0:ea7c on wlp9s0.*.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::bd93:7147:e5f0:ea7c on wlp9s0.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp9s0.IPv6 with address fe80::bd93:7147:e5f0:ea7c.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Interface wlp9s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue whoopsie[960]: [14:12:05] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.116 on wlp9s0.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp9s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.116.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue avahi-daemon[750]: Interface wlp9s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue dbus-daemon[755]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 04 14:12:05 chalchiuhtlicue systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 04 14:12:06 chalchiuhtlicue NetworkManager[756]: <info>  [1609791126.6730] device (wlp9s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```

Per some other questions, I've also run the wifi diagnostic script and put the results [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MvF8DpWm7P/).

Comment: You seem to have a malformed `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file which I suspect interfers with the default Network Manager. Did you add it for some reason? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It's possible I added it at some point--looks like there's some info there for a network I used to access frequently. Should I change or delete that file?

Comment: I suggest that you delete it and reboot. Next, tell us if the disconnects remain and, if so, we'll continue to troubleshoot.

Comment: I just did this, and it does appear that disconnects are still happening.